# How to load class into form and access it

Tags: c#, class, datagridview

I need help with accessing class from Form.

So I'll put my code so you can see what I mean.

So I have made several classes. For example:

```
public class Landscape
{
    public DataGridView grid;

    public void init()
    {
        grid = new DataGridView();
        // 
        // grid
        // 
        grid.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        grid.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        grid.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
        grid.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
        ...
        grid.AutoSizeColumnsMode = grid.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(790, 427);
        grid.TabIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

So basically this would make me datagridview on my form.

When I create form:

```
public partial class MyScreen: Form
{
    public MyScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Landscape land=new Landscape();
        land.init(); //this should draw me datagrid on my form
    }
}
```

Shouldn't this code draw me my datagrid into form?

How to achieve this?

You mean something like:

```
public partial class MyScreen: Form
{
    public MyScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Landscape land = new Landscape();
        this.Controls.Add(land.grid);
        land.init(); 
    }
}
```

But it's not working...

Comment: It is not working because you create the grid with `init()` after you have added it to the controls collection (and it is still `null` at that time). Call `init` first! Or better initialize the grid in the constructor of `Landscape`. `public Landscape() { grid = new DataGridView(); ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because you have just created a data grid view in a class but not added it to the forms controls. Add the line

```
land.init();
this.Controls.Add(land.grid);
```

To add the control to the form

Comment: Need to add the control after its been initalised